# Priority Queue of a List

Tags: python, list, dictionary, queue

I was wondering how if it is possible to use a priority queue for a list of dictionaries. For a school project, we are scrapping amazon's website and getting related product information stored in a dictionary. We have a list of dictionaries, one for each product, and we want to put it in a priority queue since that is a requirement. How would i go about it?

```js
 def __init__(self, url, related=True):
        print ("Processing: " + url)

        data = self.parse(url, related)
        self.name = data['NAME']
        self.sale_price = data['SALE_PRICE']
        self.original_price = data['ORIGINAL_PRICE']
        self.category = data['CATEGORY']
        self.availability = data['AVAILABILITY']
        self.url = data['URL']
        self.related_links = data['RELATED_LINKS']
        self.related_products = [] 
        self.related_products = sorted(self.related_products, lambda k: k([self.sale_price]))
```

So the information is parsed and plugged into the following variables. THe last line is what we are trying to replace with a priority queue algorithm. Also, the program is recursive so we plug in an Amazon URL and it gives me 5 related products for that item and ends. So we need to priority queue of the related_products. Any tips would be helpful.

Comment: Do you know why you need the priority queue? What are you prioritizing?

Comment: `from Queue import PriorityQueue`?

Comment: We are prioritizing the price. User specifies whether it is high or low.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the ``heapq`` standard module.